# Calloc error on struct pointer of pointer

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault, calloc, nfa

I have a problem with my calloc but i can't figure out why. Here is my code:

```
void ens_init(ensemble* node, ullong value, uint i){
  // *node = malloc(sizeof(struct ensemble)); # Doesn't work
  // *node = calloc(1, sizeof(struct ensemble)); # Doesn't work
  node = calloc(1, sizeof(struct ensemble));
  if (*node == NULL){
    printf("Caloc error\n");
    exit(-1);
  }
  (*node)->key = value;
  (*node)->index = i;
  (*node)->left = NULL;
  (*node)->right = NULL;
}
```

Here is my ensemble struct:

```
typedef unsigned int uint;
typedef unsigned long long int ullong;

struct ensemble{
  ullong key;
  uint index;
  struct ensemble* left;
  struct ensemble* right;
};
typedef struct ensemble* ensemble;
```

In working on non-deterministic finite automate (NFA or AFN in French) and that's why i use this kind of struct. My teacher want to program a function that will determinate a NFA and in this function we have to use a tree.

Here is how i call this function to test it

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  ensemble B = NULL;

  ens_ajouter(&B, 5, 1);

  return 0;
}
```

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Either of the two comments lines are correct.  The uncommented one is not.  You need to define what "doesn't work" means, and you need to update your question with a [mcve] that exhibits the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to call the function `ens_ajouter()` before calling your initilization function `ens_init()`. This means that the function `calloc()` is never called from the `main()` function.

I think you are making a mistake to hide the fact that the type `ensemble` is a **pointer** to a `struct ensemble`. This makes your code unreadable.

I would suggest that you change your typedef to this:

```c
typedef struct ensemble ensemble;
```

Or, even better, don't use a typedef at all. It is perfectly fine to have this kind of code:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef unsigned int uint;
typedef unsigned long long int ullong;

struct ensemble {
    ullong key;
    uint index;
    struct ensemble* left;
    struct ensemble* right;
};

void ens_init(struct ensemble** node, ullong value, uint i) {
    *node = calloc(1, sizeof(struct ensemble));
    if (*node == NULL){
        printf("Calloc error\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    (*node)->key = value;
    (*node)->index = i;
    (*node)->left = NULL;
    (*node)->right = NULL;
}

int main(void) {
    struct ensemble B;
    struct ensemble* pointer_to_B;
    pointer_to_B = &B;
    ens_init(&pointer_to_B, 5, 1);

    return 0;
}
```

Why? Because it allows you to see that there is a big problem in your allocation call. In `ens_init()`, you allocate a memory area large enough to hold a `struct ensemble` and then you store the address of this area in a pointer to a pointer to a struct (instead of a pointer to a struct). And you didn't even create a local variable of type `struct ensemble` in the `main()` function (I fixed that). You should write this instead (notice the asterisk):

```c
void ens_init(struct ensemble** node, ullong value, uint i) {
    // Asterisk added:
    *node = calloc(1, sizeof(struct ensemble));
    if (*node == NULL){
        printf("Calloc error\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    (*node)->key = value;
    (*node)->index = i;
    (*node)->left = NULL;
    (*node)->right = NULL;
}
```

Ii is strange that you have pointers to a pointer to a struct everywhere. You should avoid that if it is not necessary.